# How to display text of a page in home or custom page?

Tags: pages, homepage, customization

I have "About us" content in  a single static wp page and want to show a part of it in the front page with a read more... link.
I want to make index.php like this:

-Navigation-

*-About Us - 
-Some part of About us page content*-

-Latest News-
-The loop for latest news-

How can I do the 'about us' part?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `get_pages` function or create custom query using `WP_Query` class. The codex pages have detailed descriptions of parameters for both functions.

If this is a theme that you want to release for broader public you would probably want to create a theme options page where user sets the page that he wants to display. If it's you custom theme where you know the ID of 'About' page then you can skip the theme options part and use the page ID in either `get_pages` or `WP_Query` method.